# Deleting certain folders within a directory java

Tags: java, path, directory

Say I have a list of folders' names within a directory that has the path

`C:\Users\Desktop\Application\('folder_names')`

How would I delete certain folders within this directory and keep the ones I have stored in a list.

ie. I have a String List:

`String[] deleteList = "folder 1, folder 2, folder 3";`

and in the directory:

`C:\Users\Desktop\Application\` I only want to delete `folder 2`

How might I do this using the String List instead of explicitly call out that folder?

So far I have:

UPDATED:

```
File[] deleteList = directory.listFiles(fileFilter);
        for (File file : deleteList) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                System.out.println(file.getPath());
                if (file.getPath()
                        .equals("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Application\\folder 2")) {
                    System.out.println("got folder");
                                            FileUtils.deleteDirectory(file);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Didn't get it.");

                }
            }
        }
```

Output

```
C:\Users\U201165\Desktop\Newfolder\Newfolder(2)
got folder
C:\Users\U201165\Desktop\Newfolder\Newfolder(3)
Didn't get it.
C:\Users\U201165\Desktop\Newfolder\Newfolder(4)
Didn't get it.
C:\Users\U201165\Desktop\Newfolder\Newfolder(5)
Didn't get it.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably getting a relative path from the `getPath()`. To be sure that you are getting the absolute path from the `File` object, use:

```
if (file.getAbsolutePath().equals("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Application\\folder2")) ...
```

instead of `getPath()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your System.out is showing the file object, but in your equals method you are using file.getPath().  Put file.getPath() in your system.out so you can see what you are actually comparing.  The File object has a method like getExplicitPath() method.  You might need to be using that instead of path.  In some cases I think path just shows the file name, or the relative path not the expect one.